# Floating point difficulty in area of triangle

Tags: c++, floating-point

The output created by my program is at first accurate, then becomes 0 for all answers above 5000000. I would like to know why this is the case when I use the function I have called Heron's Area.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float heron_area(float a, float c) {
    float s = (a + a + c) / 2.0f;
    return (s - a)*sqrtf(s*(s - c));
}


int main(void) {
    int j = 18;
    float i = 10;
    for (int k = 0; k < j; k++){
        float g = i * 10;
        std::cout << heron_area(g, 1) << std::endl;
        i = g;
}


return 0;
}
```

It is potentially to do with the issue with using floating point numbers. Why am I getting the output of 0 after the last output 500000?

Comment: use double in place of float

Comment: This problem is so well known that the [solution is on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula#Numerical_stability)

Answer (score 3):

It is the issue with floating point numbers as you suspect.

If you print `a` and `s` in `heron_area`, you'll note that they very quickly become identical, making `s - a` zero.

This happens when `c` is much smaller than `a` (that is, when you have a very "pointy" triangle; your zeros appear when two sides are 10,000,000 and the third is 1).

Changing the type to `double` makes the problem appear later, but it won't go away.

You'll need to rearrange your computations if you want to handle very large differences in magnitude.

There's a solution on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula#Numerical_stability) (linked by @harold in the comments) that gives

```
Area = 0.25 * sqrt((a+(b+c)) * (c-(a-b)) * (c+(a-b)) * (a+(b-c)))
```

where `a >= b` and `b >= c`, and the brackets are necessary.
Yes, you need to worry about the order of operations.

(And there's a very detailed article [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Triangle.pdf) with an analysis of this solution.)

Answer (score 0):

As the variable a in the function heron_area grows exponentially larger and larger, the variable c, which is constant, with the value `1.0f`, becomes less and less relevant.

Due to limited precision of the floating point the expression:

```
float s = (a + a + c) / 2.0f;
```

then simplifies to:

```
float s = (a + a) / 2.0f;
```

which is the same as:

```
float s = a;
```

Thus the variables s and a have the same value, so the expression:

```
 return (s - a)*sqrtf(s*(s - c));
```

always yields `0.0f`, as the result of subtracting `s - a` is `0.0f`, and multiplying zero by anything is always zero.